# Супер-пользователь всегда

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте. Решил перейти на linux, но жутко бесят 2 вещи:

1. Постоянный запрос пароля.
2. Частая необходимость менять права для файлов.

Я один пользователь своего ПК. Линукса точно) Я понимаю, безопасность, администрирование и т.д. Нельзя ли сделать, чтоб я всегда был супер-юзером при входе в систему и все создаваемые мной файлы автоматически имели права 777? Просто надоедает вводить пароль и менять права доступа к файлам.

П.С. ИМХО, давно пора сделать такую сборку для обычных пользователей, а то такое ощущение будто все ставят ее для сетей с кучей пользователей.

Answer (score 4):

Это плохой вопрос) и не правильно всегда работать под рутом)

а так (да простят меня админы и я самого себя протить бы за это) [automatic login](http://www.linfo.org/automatic_login.html)

pps; `rm -rf /` вам в помощь)

Answer (score 3):

Выполни команду sudo passwd root. Установи пароль для рута, и производи логин из под него. Но вроде это считается не тру-вэй.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего отредактировать /etc/passwd и поставить себе UID = 0. Но проще - не значит лучше. Можно приписать себя к какой-нибудь подходящей группе (можно нескольким) (см. /etc/group)

Мне также удобно для некоторых работ запускать emacs через sudo.

Answer (score 0):

> такое ощущение будто все ставят ее для сетей с кучей пользователей

это и есть ответ на Ваш вопрос. Все никсы изначально сетевые и многопользовательские, ставьте себе DOS, он отвечает Вашим требованиям.

Comment: @gurzufnet, что ж, тогда линуксу никогда не добиться массовости использования, ибо дружелюбности, простоты и интуитивности использования в нем 0.

Comment: Wndows seven доже интерфейс KDE-шный слизала. Если Вы ставили GNOME, то будет нужно привыкнуть. На домашнем дестопе, да и на ноутах тоже, рутовые права мне нужны не чаще чем раз в неделю, обновления накатить. А Вам зачем чтобы все файлы были исполняемые?

Comment: @gurzufnet, ну решил перейти на linux для веб-разработки. Сервер вечно ругается, что не может что-то записать, считать и т.д.

Comment: ну так а зачем веб серверу читать все подряд?а писать он должен в три места (логи, темп и своя папка). Поменять разрешения на эти папки и да будет вам счастьеК интерфейсу не надо привыкать.. надо запилить его под себя :)

Comment: кто сказал, что линуксу вообще интересна эта ваша дружелюбность и массовое испльзование ? http://habrahabr.ru/post/118185/ . это система от хакеров и для хакеров, в этом правда, и заинтересована она по настоящему не в том чтобы продажи росли, а в том чтобы росла кодовая база и количество домохозяек никак этому не способствует.

Answer (score 0):

> Нельзя ли сделать, чтоб я всегда был супер-юзером при входе в систему и все создаваемые мной файлы автоматически имели права 777 Виндовые глупости в Linux дорого обходятся.

А почему вы решили переходить на Linux? Там другая идеология, другие принципы защиты.

> дружелюбности, простоты и интуитивности

Поменяйте личные привычки - и все появится. Консолью пользоваться не пробовали? ;) В винде много "дружелюбности", а толку? Сами системные области не защищены, всякая дрянь имеет возможность спокойно пролезать. С простотой тоже не все гладко - надо что-то исправить (даже если знаешь где), а низзя (или просто не хочет исправляться)! По умолчанию Майкрософт для полномочий в системе такое ставит - за голову хватаешься... Так что лучше выбирать - "удобство" или безопасность.

Comment: Сервер потому и ругается, что используется политика "разграничения ресурсов" - он работает под своим профилем, чтобы не залез куда не надо. Если вы хотите править страницы от своего юзера, то введите их в вашу группу и дайте группе права доступа на запись. т.е., условно говоря, ваши веб файлы будут иметь привязку apache:user (или наоборот, если есть желание) с правами 771 (или 751) Сервер может ругаться еще, что он логи не может писать... тогда надо дать юзеру сервера права на запись в соответствующие папки.

Comment: @Зулан, спасибо. Я понимаю почему он ругается. Но мне такие разграничения ни к чему: я единственный пользователь; на локалке проект тольк пишется, потом на сервере теститься. Вот и получается, что все эти разграничения прав мне ни к чему...

Comment: @Андрей Бакша "на локалке пишется, потом на сервере теститься". А после завершения тестирования? Вы будете единоличным пользователем проекта, или другим пользователям дадите рутовый доступ к системе? Не лучше ли тестировать проект с теми разрешениями, с которыми он будет потом реально работать?

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой дистрибутив Puppyrus, он однопользовательский, т.е. работа только от рута, за что его и критикуют, рекомендую опробовать его, а вдруг подойдет.Хотя я не понимаю, зачем часто менять права на файлы, и можно настроить вход без введения пароля, да и вообще в любом дистрибутиве можно вполне комфортно организовать работу, если грамотно к этому вопросу подойти.Надеюсь гуглом пользоваться умеете и Puppyrus найдете, впрочем он был на puppyrus.org, может и сейчас там.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы отключить пароль sudo для определенного пользователя нужно открыть файл конфигурации sudo и отключить запрос пароля следующей строчкой, например для пользователя username:

```
sudo visudo
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Сохраните изменения и закройте файл, на всякий случай напомню что в vi для перехода в режим вставки используется клавиша i, для сохранения команда :w и команда :q для выхода. Теперь sudo не будет запрашивать пароль у user'a при выполнении любых команд.